# How to conduct meta-analysis with single group percentage outcome using R?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, percentage

all. I want to conduct a meta-analysis using R on a bunch of articles. The outcomes are in percentage format and it is single group. I am wondering how could I use R to do this kind of meta-analysis? In the beginning, I thought that I could use metaprop, but after I checked the example, I think I can only use metaprop when I want to compute the proportion. For example, we have several events out of the total sample size for each article, and we can use metaprop to compute it. And because each individual has percentage, I can't back convert the percentage to the number of event. In my example, which R statement or argument should I use to deal with single group percentage data? I hope I could get the following forest plot (I found this example in an article, and they also have one group percentage data, but I can't find which R statement or argument I can use): [image: Example forest plot with single group percentage outcome]

Could anyone help me with it? Thank you!

Comment: They have standard errors and sample size neither of which I assume you have.

Comment: I don't have the standard error, but I think I can compute it based on the sample size which I have, so could you help me with it? Which R statement that I should use to get the result like that? Thank you!

Comment: Programming advice is off-topic on this list I am afraid. If you want to use the metafor package in R then http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php has many examples and tips. If you want to use the meta package I believe it has an accompanying book you can pruchase.

Comment: You almost certainly need to investigate using some transformation like the log odds especially if you have small sample sizes.